# List is empty after pushing to it (incorrect variable scope?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to react-native, and trying to develop a simple mobile app along the lines of a LifeRPG app (gamified todo list).

When the application starts up, it is meant to check for the presence of a `character.json` file, and depending on the outcome, display a certain View. However when I do this, the list I put the View in is empty after it leaves the block of code to check for file existence.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View,Text,Image,Button} from 'react-native'
import styles from "./styles"
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'

class CharacterSelect extends Component{

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}

constructor() {
    super()
}


render() {

    let displayView=[]
    RNFetchBlob.fs.exists("@assets/character.json")
        .then((exists) => {
            if (exists){
                console.warn("if")
            } else {
                console.log(displayView);
                displayView.push(<View style={styles.viewCharacter}><Text>Oopsie, no character!</Text><Button title="press" onPress={()=>this.checkCharacterExists()}></Button></View>)
                console.log(displayView);
            }
        })

    console.log(displayView)



    const {} = styles
    return(
        <PaperProvider>
        <View style={styles.viewTitle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Welcome to RpgDoIt!</Text>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={require('@assets/titlelogo.png')}/>
        </View>



        {displayView}

        </PaperProvider>
    )
}
}

export default CharacterSelect
```

It should produce a View shown in the else block, but instead nothing happens, and the array is empty when it hits the `console.log` outside of the previous block of code.

Comment: Welcome @Tizos! i would recommend giving this a read: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

It will give you valuable information about the best practices regarding updating information on your screen in response to events such as data loads.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is empty at the console log because you push to it asynchronously.

```
let displayView=[]
    RNFetchBlob.fs.exists("@assets/character.json")
        .then((exists) => {
             // EVERYTHING here happens asynchronously. I.e., it is likely (but not necessarily) executed after the console log.
        })

    console.log(displayView)
```

If you would like to console log after the push occurs, you would either 1) move the console.log inside the `then`; or 2) use the `await` keyword and mark you function `async`.

Look into understanding async code (not necessarily JS specific, but in general) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately this did solve my issue,the list is still not populated before reaching the return() method

Comment: We can't fix ur issue because it's larger than your code snippet. my advice still stands, look into understanding async code.